# Setting up Azure to Sync Contacts in Custom Program, Tasks and Pricing

Tags: azure

We have our own application that stores contacts in an SQL database.   What all is involved in getting up and running in the cloud so that each user of the application can have his own, private list of contacts, which will be synced with both his computer and his phone?

I am trying to get a feeling for what Azure might cost in this regard, but I am finding more abstract talk than I am concrete scenarios.

Let's say there are 1,000 users, and each user has 1,000 contacts that he keeps in his contacts book.   No user can see the contacts set up by any other user.  Syncing should occur any time the user changes his contact information.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd argue that your solution won't be cost affective. 1,000 databases * $4.995 = almost $5k a month. Alternatively, you an host your own SQL Server via Windows Azure but will potentially need to bring your own license. You should really think about a more multi-tenant friendly solution.

Comment: I was thinking it would only have 1 database, but each of our customers would have their own ID, thereby permitting us to use that field to filter access to each customer's own contacts.

Answer (score 1):

While the Windows Azure Cloud Platform is not intended to compete directly with consumer-oriented services such as Dropbox, it is certainly intended as a platform for building applications that do that. So your particular use case is a good one for Windows Azure: creating a service for keeping contacts in sync, scalable across many users, scalable in the amount of data it holds, and so forth.

Making your solution is multi-tenant friendly (per comment from @BrentDaCodeMonkey) is key to cost-efficiency. Your data needs are for 1K users x 1K contacts/user = 1M contacts. If each contact is approx 1KB then we are talking about approx 1GB of storage.

Checking out the [pricing calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/pricing), the at-rest storage cost is $9.99/month for a Windows Azure SQL Database instance for 1GB (then $13.99 if you go up to 2GB, etc. - refer to calculator for add'l projections and current pricing).

Then you have data transmission (Bandwidth) charges. Though since the pricing calculator says "The first 5 GB of outbound data transfers per billing month are also free" you probably won't have any costs with current users, assuming moderate smarts in the sync.

This does not include the costs of your application. What is your application, how does it run, etc? Assuming there is a client-side component, (typically) this component cannot be trusted to have the database connection. This would therefore require a server-side component running that could serve as a gatekeeper for the database. (You also, usually, don't expose the database to all IP addresses - another motivation for channeling data through a server-side component.) This component will also cost money to operate. The costs are also in the [pricing calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/pricing) - but if you chose to use a Windows Azure Web Site that could be free. An excellent approach might be the nifty ASP.NET [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) stack that has recently been released. Using the Web API, you can implement a nice REST API that your client application can access securely. Windows Azure Web Sites can host Web API endpoints. Check out the "reserved instance" capability too.

I would start out with Windows Azure Web Sites, but as my service grew in complexity/sophistication, check out the Windows Azure Cloud Service (as a more advance approach to building server-side components).

Comment: Thanks for this write-up.   It sounds like it could easily be done for less than $100/mo.   That's sort-of what I was looking for.   Can you point me to where to read up on deploying this type of application in Azure?  Basically, a "How to build a Hello World database app, deploy it in Azure and watch it sync to all your registered devices?"